# Assembly.GetType() and typeof() return different types?

Tags: c#, reflection, types

Suppose you are given a Class.dll assembly compiled from the following simple code:

```
namespace ClassLibrary
{
    public class Class
    {
    }
}
```

And consider a different project with the above Class.dll as a project reference and with the following code:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"Class.dll");

Type reflectedType = assembly.GetType("ClassLibrary.Class");
Type knownType = typeof(ClassLibrary.Class);

Debug.Assert(reflectedType == knownType);
```

The assertion fails, and I don't understand why.

The assertion succeeds if I replace the ClassLibrary.Class with, say, the System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex class and Class.dll with System.dll, so I'm guessing it has something to do with the project properties ? some Compilation switch perhaps?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is load contexts: assemblies loaded via .LoadFrom are kept in a different "pile" than those loaded by Fusion (.Load). The types are actually different to the CLR. Check [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57143.aspx) for more detail from a CLR architect.

Comment: You nailed it - using Assembly.Load() resolved the issue. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You're probably loading two different copies of the same assembly.

Compare `knownType.Assembly` to `reflectedType.Assembly` in the debugger, and look at the paths and versions.

Answer (score 2):

I would imagine that you are not referencing the same assembly that you are loading from disk.

This example (when compiled as `Test.exe`) works just fine:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

class Example
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"Test.exe");

        Type reflectedType = assembly.GetType("Example");
        Type knownType = typeof(Example);

        Console.WriteLine(reflectedType == knownType);
    }
}
```

Comment: its an asp.net mvc application without external reference to other class libraries.